# Continue for loop when observable is complete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, observable

I'm calling an `http.get` service inside a for loop, my code is working fine, the problem is that the loop continues even if the observable is not complete.

this is my code:

Angular 2 Component:

```
let max = 5;
for (let i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    let boxNo = i > 9 ? "0" + i : "00" + i;
    this.invoiceService.generateChecklist(prefixAndLetter, boxNo).subscribe(
        result => {
            console.log(result.data);
        }
    )
}
```

MVC Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GenerateChecklist(string prefixAndLetter, string boxNo)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prefixAndLetter))
    {
        return Json(new { success = true, data = boxNo }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is the result i'm getting:

```
002
003
001
005
004
```

Comment: I am not an angular expert but I am pretty sure it is supposed to work that way. You make asynchronous calls to the server in a loop, so your loop will not wait and continue making asynchronous requests. Whenever, a response comes, the handler will execute in the `subscribe` and as soon as it is done, the loop will continue.

Comment: Yes, that's how this code is meant to run.

Comment: @CodingYoshi. What you wrote is wrong: "Whenever a response comes, the handler will execute in the subscribe and *as soon as it is done*, the loop will continue". **Async means you don't know when the subscribe is executed**, so there is no "as soon as it is done, the loop will continue". What the loop does is it **attaches a bunch of subscribe callbacks** to a bunch of observables *without waiting for anything*. You have no control over when the callbacks are invoked.

Comment: @angularfrance no it is not wrong. If the loop creates the first x async calls there is a possibility one of the async calls may have returned. Therefore there will be something in the event loop. At some point the handler code will need to be executed and that is when the code can only do that, since there is one thread, so it will carry the code in the handler to completion before it can make another async request. It cannot do 2 things concurrently. I know what async means.

Comment: "Async means you don't know when the subscribe is executed" is exactly my point. When the subscriber is being executed there is a possibility that only 3 async requests have been dispatched. As soon as the handler is complete, it may make another async request.

Comment: @angularfrance and then you say `so there is no "as soon as it is done, the loop will continue"`. Actually there is. If a response has returned, while the handler is being executed, nothing else can be executed and the loop will have to wait. As soon as it's done executing the handler it MAY continue with the loop or it may have another item in the event loop.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use `concatAll`, which waits for all async calls complete before notifying subscribers:

```
let boxes = [];
let max = 5;
for (let i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    let boxNo = i > 9 ? "0" + i : "00" + i;
    boxes.push(boxNo);
}

Observable.of(boxes.map(t=> this.invoiceService.generateChecklist(prefixAndLetter, t)))
     .concatAll()
     .subscribe(result => {
           result.forEach((item)=> console.log(item.data));
      });
```

Comment: I'm afraid your code is wrong. You're using the `concatAll()` operator from RxJS on a plain array (`boxes`), it won't work. `concatAll()` needs an observable to operate: `Observable.of(boxes.map(...)).concatAll().subscribe()`

Comment: You're right, pixelbits, I shouldn't be so negative. Code was not all wrong, it was just not 100% right ;-)